# Linq FirstOrDefault(<condition>).Attribute vs Where(<condition>).Select(a => Attribute).FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, linq

I've been cleaning up some old code and came accross a few queries of the following structure:

```cs
var attribute = DbSet.Where(<condition>).Select(a => a.Attribute).SingleOrDefault();
```

and as I'm trying to make the code more readable I would change that to:

```cs
var attribute = DbSet.SingleOrDefault(<condition>).Attribute;
```

therefore shortening the statement.

But now I'm wondering which of the two is better for performance, and which is better for memory management.

Comment: To be equivalent, the second should be `DbSet.SingleOrDefault(<condition>)?.Attribute` (note the "?")

Comment: @KlausGütter Actually it would need to be `DbSet.SingleOrDerault(<condition>)?.Attribute ?? default` because if `Attribute` is an `int` then the first one would return the default of 0, but what you have would return a null `int?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. `DbSet.SingleOrDefault(<condition>).Attribute` will fetch whole row from database and pass it over the network to you application. So if your table has many columns and/or columns containing a lot of data (big stings, some binary data) then first one should be faster cause it will fetch only data which is actually needed.

Also note that `SingleOrDefault` can return null, so without null check you can get `NullReferenceException`.